# Incrementing an IEnumerator/IEnumerable while using yield

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable

I am trying to yield iterate through a collection and if the collection is empty then call an increment method that will get the next set of results. When the increment says there are no more results then the yield with break;

I can not use (i think) a standard IEnumerator with MoveNext() etc as the increment method returns two different types of data.

I have tried an example below but it stops after one itteration. I am hoping there is a much easier way to do this (or at least is possible just I have a bug).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = new Query();

    foreach(var s in query.Q1())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    foreach (var s in query.Q2())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Query
{
    int i = 0;
    bool complete;
    List<string> q1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> q2 = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> Q1()
    {
        if (complete)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        if (!q1.Any() && !complete)
        {
            Increment();
        }
        if (q1.Any())
        {
            foreach (var s in q1)
            {
                yield return s;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Q2()
    {
        if (complete)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        if (!q2.Any() && !complete)
        {
            Increment();
        }
        if (q2.Any())
        {
            foreach (var s in q2)
            {
                yield return s;
            }
        }
    }

    void Increment()
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
                    // simulate getting two types of data back (parent and two children) from datasource
            q1.Add((1 * (i + 1)).ToString());
            q2.Add("A: " + (1 * (i + 1)).ToString());
            q2.Add("B: " + (1 * (i + 1)).ToString());

            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            complete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
1
A: 1
B: 1
```

Any ideas on a better way of doing this or where I am going wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my rough and ready fix:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Q1()
{
    var index = 0;

    if (!complete)
    {
        while (!complete)
        {
            var count = q1.Count();

            if (index + 1 == count)
            {
                for (var x = index; index < count; index++)
                {
                    yield return q1[index];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Increment();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var s in q1)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding elements only to `q2` list. Thus when you call `Q1` iterator, you are exiting it after checking

```
if (q1.Any())
```

When you calling `Q2` iterator, you exit it after

```
if (q2.Any())
{
     foreach (var s in q2)
     {
         yield return s;
     }
}
```

This `foreach` loop is executed only once and it returns only three items which where added to `q2` during single `Increment` call in `Q1` iterator.

It's not very clear what you want to achieve, but here is the way you can use loop for generating return values of iterator

```
public IEnumerable<string> Q2()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // start from 1
    {
        yield return i.ToString(); // do not multiply by 1
        yield return "A: " + i;    // .ToString() is not necessary 
        yield return "B: " + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the Increment method of yielding was mealy my bad example (shouldn't be on SO at midnight!) of a long running process you did get me on the right track by saying my iterator was exiting early.